# Magento 2 Customer Id is not updating after login

Tags: magento2, customer, login, customer-session, catalog-prodct-view.xml

I have a form in the product view section. In this form, I am keeping the logged-in user's id hidden. First I log in as one customer and then log out from that account. Again I log in as another user, but still it shows the 1st customer's id.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to full page cache behavior and depends on full page cache type you can use different workarounds

You can use attribute `cacheable="false"` for your form block, but I don't suggest to do this because it will affect to performance on PDP.

The best way to process this scenario is get customer data from local storage and pass into form with JS.

Magento doesn't pass raw customer id into frontend and you can create plugin for `\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer::getSectionData` and pass raw or encoded customer id.

For access to customer data you can use

```js
require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function(customerData) {
    'use strict';
    let customer = customerData.get('customer')();
    // check if customer has required data and make your logic
});
```

Comment: I have created a custom section for this and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom section for this.

Step 1: For creating a custom section we need to give an entry in etc/frontend/di.xml file.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customsection" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Section\CustomerData\CustomSection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Step 2: we will create getSectionData() in Namespace\Section\CustomerData\CustomSection.php file. This function is responsible for the setting data in different sections.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Section\CustomerData;

use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\View;
use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

class CustomSection implements SectionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CurrentCustomer
     */
    protected $currentCustomer;

    /**
     * @var View
     */
    private $customerViewHelper;

    /**
     * @param CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
     * @param View $customerViewHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        View $customerViewHelper
    ) {
        $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
        $this->customerViewHelper = $customerViewHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getSectionData()
    {
        if (!$this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId()) {
            return [];
        }

        $customer = $this->currentCustomer->getCustomer();
        return [
            'customerId' => $customer->getId()
        ];
    }
}
```

Step 3: Now, we will fetch the message that we set in our custom section. For this we call our template file customsection.phtml on product view page.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="custom_section" template="Namespace_Section::customsection.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 4: Template file: customsection.phtml

```
<div class="pd-customsection"data-bind="scope: 'section'">
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" data-bind="value: customsection().customerId">
</div>

    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "section": {
                            "component": "Namespace_Section/js/section"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Step 5: Namespace/Section/frontend/web/js/section.js file.

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';
    
    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.customsection = customerData.get('customsection'); //pass your custom section name
        }
    });
});
```